# Humorous mathematical essays

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, examples-counterexamples, big-list

Even though there are plenty examples of [mathematical jokes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/1083/do-good-math-jokes-exist), the mathematical literature is (in many cases) pretty dull. Nevertheless, examples exist in which an essay makes you smile with a nice pun when talking about Galois theory or something...

> Can you provide examples of humorous/funny mathematical essays?

**EXAMPLE ANSWER**

A classical example is the essay ["A Contribution to the Mathematical Theory of Big Game Hunting"](http://math.ucdenver.edu/~wcherowi/mathmajor/archive/catchlion.pdf) by Ralph P. Boas (under a pseudonym) which was published in the *Mathematical Monthly*

**UPDATE**

Building on the comments by @Ahmed Hussein and @Hans Ludmark there is already a list of [colorful language](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22299/what-are-some-examples-of-colorful-language-in-serious-mathematics-papers) and a list of [memorable titles](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44326/most-memorable-titles) so I changed my question.

Comment: Looks like a horseshoe to me.

Comment: There was once an article about self-referential structures in, IIRC, American Mathematical Monthly. Its list of references had a single item, the article itself. The only theorem of the article boldly stated that Theorem 1. in reference [1] is false. Where they usually place a photo of the author(s), there was a selfie taken with the aid of a mirror, the subject shown taking a picture et cetera...

Comment: The margin notes in *Concrete Mathematics*, perhaps. Or the Romeo and Juliet interpretation of linear ODEs in Strogatz's *Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos* (Section 5.3, especially the answers to exercise 5.3.1).

Comment: Check out: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22299/what-are-some-examples-of-colorful-language-in-serious-mathematics-papers

Comment: Or some of the titles mentioned here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/44326/most-memorable-titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere between a joke and an essay,  is Impure Math.  http://www.snowman-jim.org/science/humor/impure-math.html